# Do I need to add guest users to authenticate with Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm writing an app that authenticates with Azure B2C.

For each user that I want to authenticate, do I need to add them as a guest user in my B2C portal?

Or is there a setting that will allow my app to authenticate anyone, without having to add them as a guest user in the portal?

Answer (score 1):

Adding them as guests won't allow them to authenticate.

Please see the [Overview of user accounts in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview).

Consumer account can be used for B2C authentication. But Guest account is different from Consumer account.

You can sign up external users to B2C to enable them to log in. This is exactly what B2C should do.

If you don't want to sign them up to B2C as the local account, you can [Add an identity provider to your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider#select-an-identity-provider).

Select the corresponding idp, for example, if your external user is AAD user, you need to [Set up sign-in for a specific Azure Active Directory organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy); if your external user is Google account, you should [Set up sign-up and sign-in with a Google account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

After you configure this, there will be additional sign-in button for those idps. You can sign in your external user directly without sign-up.

Answer (score 0):

Just to amplify @AllenWu:

If you create a guest user on B2C, you are creating an admin. user of that portal.

You are not creating a user.

B2C can handle millions of customers so you don't want any help desk involvement.

So B2C has user self-service registration, self-service password reset etc.

Once they have done that, the user can sign in.